# android webview zoom not working

Tags: android

i have integrated a webview in my activity.

```
    accwebView.setClickable(false);
    accwebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    accwebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    accwebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    accwebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    accwebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

i did not want the links to be clicked so i have set

> setClickable(false)

to false.

Its working fine on nexus one(2.3.6).But when i tried it with samsung galaxy(2.2.1) zoom is not working.its only working in one condition if i comment or diable

> //setClickable(false)

But i did not want links on the page to be clickable at the same time default zoom to be working.Please help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It work for me.Put inside onTuchEvent override method

```
                webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Now i have remove condition

Comment: `accwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());              private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if ( event.getAction() > MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN) {
                accwebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                accwebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            } else {
                accwebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                accwebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }   `

Comment: why are your overriding on touch inside webviewclient.Override as part of activity as we override onCreate() onresume() etc.I have used this code in my application and its working as charm

Comment: tried it as well on activity override but zoom is not happening :(

Comment: tell me plz why you disable zoom control in else cause of your i need to enable zoom in all conditions.Thanks

Comment: If you touch with one finger then my code will zoom that was my requirement you can use without condition.Then your webview will zoom when you touch it

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

Comment: this worked for me now my links are not responding to clicks and zoom is working as well. :)

Comment: On August 2016, on a Android M, I used both lines suggested on the webview initialization and zoom started working. Outside any event, right after webview creation inside onCreate

webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);